# Unable to sort records in active admin by virtual attribute

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, activeadmin

Unable to sort records in active admin by virtual attribute.

I have a model `Competition`.

Competition has 2 columns named `starts_at` and `ends_at`.

Competitions can have any of these status regarding their `starts_at` and `ends_at` dates.

- **Open** if `starts_at < Time.now && ends_at > Time.now`
- **Closed** if `Time.now > ends_at`
- **Not Opened** if `starts_at > Time.now`

I want to apply sorting on status in this order(and reverse too)

1. **Open** on top
2. **Closed** after open
3. **Not Opened** in the end

File `/admin/competition.rb`

Method: `index`

Virtual Attribute: `Status`

```
column "Status" , sortable: true do |competition|
    competition.status
end
```

File `app/model/copetition.rb`

method to get status

```
def status
    return 'Unknown' unless (starts_at && ends_at)
    return 'Not Opened' if Time.now < starts_at
    return 'Open' if (Time.now > starts_at && Time.now < ends_at)
    return 'Closed' if Time.now > ends_at
end
```

I could not find a way to apply this kind of sorting.

Additional Information

`'rails', '4.2.6'`

`ruby '2.2.4'`

`'activeadmin', '1.0.0.pre4'`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to sort by virtual attribute in `activeadmin` since sorting is performed on DB level.

However, you can use the same logic to calculate the needed field in SQL and use it instead.

You have to modify the `activeadmin`'s default collection SQL query and add your calculated field in order to be able to use it for sorting.

```
# /admin/competition.rb

ActiveAdmin.register Competition do
  # modify the collection SQL query to add the needed field
  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      super.select(
        "competitions.*,
         CASE
         WHEN starts_at < NOW() THEN 3
         WHEN ends_at > NOW() THEN 2
         ELSE 1
         END AS status_from_sql"
      )
    end
  end

  # using the added field for sorting
  column "Status" , sortable: "status_from_sql" do |competition|
    competition.status
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the raw SQL with [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#order`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order):

```
.order("
  IF(starts_at < NOW() AND ends_at > NOW(), 1,
    IF (NOW() > ends_at, 0, -1)) DESC
")
```

Comment: Actually I am using active_admin for this. Using default sorting functionality.

I don't know where to apply this piece of code. 

I don't have `status` column in competitions table.
How to override the basic functionality of active admin.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Do you see any mention of `status` in the snippet above? This will **order the records in the database**, which is a correct approach. Apply it to where you select the records from the database.

Comment: It is active_admin'd default sorting. 
When we apply `sortable` on any column in `active admin` then user can sort by those column(either `ASC` or `DESC`). and active admin queries to that particular column. But I don't have that column. 


When I use  `column "Status" , sortable: true` then params

Comment: You have to handle the case manually. Developing applications is sometimes about writing some code, not only about using the 3rd-party libraries.

Comment: This is my index action in `active admin`---
`index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column "Name", :title
    column "Organizer Name", :user_id    
    column "Status" , sortable: true do |competition|
      competition.status
    end
    column :starts_at
    column :ends_at
    column :group_id
    column :submissions, sortable: 'competitions.submissions_count' do |competition|
      link_to  competition.try(:submissions_count).to_i,  admin_competition_submissions_path(competition)
    end    
    actions
  end`

Comment: Actually my whole admin panel is built on active_admin.
I just need a way to sort it out. Thanks